# How to apply circular motion for sprites in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

I want four sprites to orbit a single origin point. But if I use like this

```
        sprite_p1_avatar = new Sprite(dummyText);
        sprite_p1_avatar.setPosition(200, 200);
        sprite_p1_avatar.setOrigin(100, 100);

        sprite_p2_avatar = new Sprite(dummyText);
        sprite_p2_avatar.setPosition(300, 300);
        sprite_p2_avatar.setOrigin(100, 100);

        sprite_p3_avatar = new Sprite(dummyText);
        sprite_p3_avatar.setPosition(400, 400);
        sprite_p3_avatar.setOrigin(100, 100);

        sprite_p4_avatar = new Sprite(dummyText);
        sprite_p4_avatar.setPosition(500, 500);
        sprite_p4_avatar.setOrigin(100, 100);

        sprite_p1_avatar.rotate(40 * delta);

        sprite_p1_avatar.draw(batch);

        sprite_p2_avatar.rotate(40 * delta);
        sprite_p2_avatar.draw(batch);

        sprite_p3_avatar.rotate(40 * delta);
        sprite_p3_avatar.draw(batch);

        sprite_p4_avatar.rotate(40 * delta);
        sprite_p4_avatar.draw(batch);
```

the sprite get inverted while revolving, as these sprites are profile pictures of users I want them  to stay straight while orbiting at every point. Is there any way to move the sprites along a circular path without rotating.

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you provide screenshots?

Comment: I can't provide you n answer, but here is the link for the formula. http://www.physicsclassroom.com/calcpad/circgrav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a 'helper'-Vector that is representing the distance from your origin-point.

Like that:

```
private Vector2 origin;
private Vector2 distance;

void ctor(){
    origin = new Vector2();
    distance = new Vector2(0, 100);
}

public void update(float Delta){
    origin.set(200, 200);
    distance.rotate(40 * Delta);
    Vector2 newPos = origin.add(distance);
    sprite.setPosition(newPos.x - sprite.width/2, newPos.y - sprite.height/2);
}
```

Comment: but how to change the position of sprite each time? and what's the 'degree' here.

Comment: you Change the Position of the sprite in your update method. The 'degree' value is the desired angle of your sprite in relation to the origin Point.

Answer (score 3):

From your code it's clear that you are only rotating the individual sprites while their origin is set to 100,100

You have to move the sprites around the center(100,100) by changing their positions like earth moves around sun.

origin is for the sprite rotation centre.

So give a radius to your shape like 
r = 50,
centre of the circle (cx,cy)=(100,100)

calculate point on the perimeter of the circle applying geometry

```
double radianDegrees = Math.toRadians(d);
double updatedX = cx + r * Math.cos(radianDegrees);
double updatedY = cy + r * Math.sin(radianDegrees);
```

and increase the angle by a which is the rate you want to move the sprites

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you be more specific ,like how to apply this??

Comment: what is the angle d here and how to find it

Comment: d is the angle you want to increase in every frame, starting from 0 and reset at 360.

Comment: how to do this programmatically. I have no idea,